# Simple probability question with javascript

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, average

Some function outputs +0, +1, +2 or +3
The probability of getting:

+0 : 31%

+1 : 40%,

+2 : 20%,

+3 : 9%

Totaling 100%

What is the average decimal/float +X from this function?
For example if all of them were 25% then the average +X would be 1.50.

Came up with the following but I'm not sure it's correct:
`((plus0*0) + (plus1*1) + (plus2*2) + (plus3*3)) / 100 = X`

Comment: I assume you want to find the weighted average? That is, $$X = \dfrac{0\times 31 + 1 \times 40 + 2\times 20 + 3\times 9}{100}.$$

Comment: " For example if all of them were 25% then the average +X would be 1.50. "  Why? What do you mean?

Comment: @an4s Awesome! Thanks :) If that's right then the formula I had was right.

Comment: @DanielS. if the output of the function was a continuum from 0 to 3, and each digit had a weighting of 25% then the average output of the function would be right in the middle of the range (1.5)